# Slope coefficients of regression of two categories variable with continuous variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data

If I have the following regression model:

Where stock price is continuous dependent variable and earnings is a sole continuous independent variable.

Earnings extremity is a categorical variable (three categories: small extremity, moderate extremity and large extremity), earning extremity1 = 1 if moderate extremity and 0 otherwise and earnings extremity2 = 1 if large extremity and 0 otherwise

Negative earnings is a categorical variable (two categories: negative earnings and positive earnings), negative earnings =1 if negative earnings and 0 otherwise (if positive earnings)

I used intercept and slope dummies

This is the model

Stock Price = 0 + 1 earnings extremity1 + 2 earnings extremity2 + 3 negative earnings + C0 earnings + C1 earnings * earnings extremity1 + C2 earnings * earnings extremity2 + C3 earnings * negative earnings + e

I am interested in slope coefficients

My questions

How can I interpret (C1 + C3) and (C2 + C3) (assuming that each is significantly negative)?

How can I interpret (C3 - C1) and (C2 - C3) (assuming that each is significantly negative)?

Thank you very much
Best regards

Wael

Comment: Why do you want to interpret the sum or difference of two coefficients?